# How to read Bluebirds' promise structure?

Tags: promise, bluebird

I started using Bluebird and I see that it changes the structure of the promise.

Everything is now with an underscore so it's private (?), so what indicates if the promise was fulfilled or failed or pending?

[image]

In contrast with the original structure:

[image]

Comment: For what you need to know internal structure of promise object? Is `.then()` not enough to know the state of promise?
If you are looking for **pending** - there is API for it - http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/ispending.html

Comment: I want to know what's going on with the promises and why `Promise.all` doesn't fulfill. @KrzysztofSafjanowski

Comment: You may want to read how Promises (`then`, `catch`, `all` e `race`) work: https://www.promisejs.org/

Comment: @MarcoL what is race?

Comment: What you want to use if you think you may have forever pending Promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets have 3 promises - 2 resolved and 1 in rejected state and mix them with one another promise - timeout that will be rejected after 1 second.

`Promise.race` returns promise as soon one of the promises in the given array resolves or rejects.

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");

let p1 = Promise.resolve('first')
let p2 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1e8)
})
let p3 = Promise.resolve('third')

Promise.race([
  Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(() => console.log('ok')),
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 1e3)) // rejected after 1000 ms
])
.catch(() => console.log(`Promise p2 is in pending state: ${p2.isPending()}`))
```

`.catch()` will logs `Promise p2 is in pending state: true`

Comment: What if some of them stay `pending` forever?

Comment: After what time you want to detect state? Some timeout?

Comment: Lets add some timeouts and check status of `p2` after